# how to render react component in separate page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to move to dashboard page after login i use history push method but its appearing on the same page i need in different page, how to overcome it?

my dashboard.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const  Dashboard = (props) => {
 console.log(props);
    return <h2>Hi, this is Dashboard page</h2>;
  }


export default Dashboard;
```

my redirect code is:

```
if(status === "success"){
                this.setState({
                    errMsg: "",
                    loading:false
                  });
                  this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
            }
```

my app.js code is:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
   </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: its appearing like this]

Comment: Where exactly is `this.props.history.push('/dashboard');` being called? Can you show us the full code?

Comment: So after successful login you want to open `/dashboard` on a new tab?

Comment: after login success i need to redirect to this dashboard component

Comment: @mkamranhamid yes you are right

Comment: if you want to open a new new tab use `target="_blank"` property of anchor. So your code will look like `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Router` will render all matched paths, and `"/"` matches all paths. You can either specify the `exact` prop on the `"/"` login route, or use a `Switch` to render *only* the first match.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
   </Router>
  );
}
```

or

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
   </Router>
  );
}
```

[Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
>   location.

Swap the order of routes to more specific paths are matched first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your Router and Routes.

Try to use something like this.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
   </Router>
  );
}
```

React-router-dom will check for an exact match.